# Passing same value to more variables

Tags: bash

I have written a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

dirs=()
dirs[0]=`export DIR_1=./dir1 && echo $DIR_1`
dirs[1]=`export DIR_2=./dir2 && echo $DIR_2`

for v in ${dirs[@]}; do

  echo $v;
  mkdir -p $v

done

# Here is my question: why it is null???
echo $DIR_1
```

How can I both do export the param and echo the value in same line?

Comment: ...something like export DIR_1=./dir1; echo $DIR_1?... (instead of echo you can use any statement)

Comment: what do you mean "instead of echo"?

Comment: Are you running the echo $DIR_1 after running your script? In which case it will be null. If you want to persist the value of environment variables you set it a script to be available after the script exits then run it as  ".  <script name>"  That is a dot followed by a space followed by the script file name.

Comment: Its hard to see what you are trying to achieve here. `DIR_1=./dir1;dirs[0]=$DIR_1;echo $DIR_1` saves you a whole subshell. What motivates the `&&` - assigning a constant to a variable will never fail surely.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove yes, 3 lines. that's what I mean "I wanna do it in one line" ;) I donnot know if that's possible though ;)  just like "a=b=1 // a=1 also b =1"

Comment: `read -r a b  <<< $(echo 1 2) ; echo "$a and $b"`  I think is the idiomatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "<<<" operator in bash is called a here string.

If you want to do multiple assignments on a single line use `read` as follows

```
read -r var1 var2 var3 <<< $(echo val1 val2 val3)
```

Each word in the string you echo will get assigned to each variable.

Comment: I accept it. Though I have to write the same value twice

Comment: @ZhaoRocky Yes that's true, but I cant think of a language where you can say `a,b=1` - though I'm willing to be contradicted if someone knows of one.

Answer (score 1):

After my comment, I post this reply which explains what I meant with "instead of echo..."

The original line of code is:

```
dirs[0]=`export DIR_1=./dir1 && echo $DIR_1`
```

Here, the export does not work because it is executed under another instance of the shell, as you used the back ticks. In the child shell the export is executed, but the modified environment can not be "ported back".

Instead, to obtain the same, but working, result, you can write:

```
export DIR_1=./dir1;  dirs[0]=$(echo $DIR_1)
```

The above line is equivalent to your original one, it makes exactly the same thing, included the strange way to assign to dir[0], but the export is executed in the local shell and exported to all the future childs. What I meant was you can write any command after the "export DIR_1...", even dirs[0]=...

Comment: @Biffen thank you for editing, these backticks drive me crazy with my keyboard!

Comment: I probably should have talked about this in my own answer. Good work :)

Comment: @linuxfan thanks a lot for making that clear. I agree with you. Just for fun to know if any possible in one expression ;)